# Cannot boot after clean install of Windows 10 32-bit

Tags: windows-10, boot, 32-bit

After looking through this site, I'm still having trouble changing a Windows 10 64-bit machine into a Windows 10 32-bit machine.

After doing a clean install of Windows 10 32-bit, the installation says that it's restarting the PC.  Instead of booting, however, it goes straight back into the install/repair menu.  Furthermore, there is no SSD in the boot order list (only the USB and NIC).

I've tried:

-GPT / UEFI USB boot disk with UEFI boot options selected: PC does a 'pre-boot system check' and then doesn't boot to windows.

-MBR / Legacy USB boot disk with Legacy boot options selected: Goes to installation (even if previously installed) vs booting to windows.  Strangely, bootrec /scanos says that there are 0 OSs installed.  The SSD or Windows Boot Manager are not even options in the boot order if done this way.

If what I've read is correct, 32-bit Windows *has* to be installed with Legacy boot options selected.

Comment: Let me guess: your SSD is a M.2 PCIe type? May be your BIOS does not support access to PCIe devices in legacy mode. Anyway what do you want to install a 32bit Windows version?

Comment: Yes, it is.  And this could be possible -but I can't confirm/refute this.  Would there be a way to check?  It needs to be 32-bit due to limitations of the software this machine's user will need.

Comment: I've done some more digging and it seems that this is impossible per Dell's support site.  You CANNOT boot from an internal drive in legacy mode and you can only boot in UEFI mode if you've got a 64-bit OS installed.

Comment: Your issue is your system isn’t compatible with a 32-bit OS if you want to use your NVMe drive.  This is a know issue with NVMe drives.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested the user's 32-bit software on Windows 10 64-bit? Most 32-bit stuff runs well, or at most, with a Compatibility tweak.

[image: Compatibility Mode dlg]

If it *must* be run on a 32 bit system, try a 32-bit Linux distro such as [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) [32-bit 18.04 is an upgrade option, after installing 16.04], using *wine*. It runs about half the Windows software I've tried.